# Find common items in two lists (Scala)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

A newbie Scala question .

I'm trying to implement a function that receive two Lists ,find a common item , than make manipulation and create a new list

I have a case class

```
case class weightedFruits(fruits: Set[String], weight: Double)
```

and two lists `weightedFruitsList` and `filteredWeightedFruitsList`:

```
// set is sorted 
val weightedFruitsList = List(
weightedFruits(Set("banana"), 200),
weightedFruits(Set("banana", "orange"), 180),
weightedFruits(Set("banana", "orange", "apple"), 170),
weightedFruits(Set("feijoa", "fig"), 201))


 //filtered List , Set sorted, contains "melon" as last member
val filteredWeightedFruitsList = List(
weightedFruits(Set("banana", "melon"), 250),
weightedFruits(Set("banana", "orange", "melon"), 270),
weightedFruits(Set("banana", "orange", "apple", "melon"), 365))
```

I'd like to go over each item in `filteredWeightedFruitsList` , find same items in  `weightedFruitsList`, do a small manipulation and create a new `List[weightedFruits]`

My (not working yet) code :

```
def conf :Option[List[weightedFruits]] = {

  for (filtered <- filteredWeightedFruitsList){

     weightedFruitsList.find{

      case x if ( x.fruits equals filtered.fruits.dropRight(1) ) => return weightedFruits(x.fruits, x.weight / filtered.weight)]
      case _ => false
   }    
  }    
}
```

With this code I've two problems:
1) `type mismatch;  found : Unit required: Option`

2) `type mismatch; found : weightedFruits required: Option[List[weightedFruits]]`

Any thoughts are welcome . Sorry if my question make you mad...

Last question maybe there is more efficient way to make this task ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe worth noting that Sets are not sorted. For that you'd need [SortedSets](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html#sorted-sets)

Comment: Could you please give an example of desired function's signature, inputs, and output? Example `def add1(x: Int): Int`, input: `add1(42)`, output: `43`.

Comment: desired function input two `List[weightedFuits]`  ,the output is list too .  `def conf ( filtered: List[weightedFruits] , full: List[weightedFruits]): List[weightedFruits]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type mismatch; found : weightedFruits required: Option[List[weightedFruits]]` is caused by your `conf` method doesn't return `Option[List[weightedFruits]]` type result. maybe you can try use `for yield` to do this.

```
def conf :List[weightedFruits] = for {
   f <- filteredWeightedFruitsList
   t <- weightedFruitsList.find(i => f.fruits.dropRight(1) == i.fruits)
} yield t.copy(weight = t.weight / f.weight)
```

`copy` method will copy `case class`, and override some fields by using `name`

Comment: Look nice , please add some words about `t.copy`